# Ruby string concat with webrick

Tags: ruby

I have this piece of code which I want to modify (new to ruby)

```
hRand = rand(10).to_s
if( request.path == '/test' )
    response.status          = 200
    response['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    response.body            = File.read('C:\\#{hRand}.html')
```

When I access localhost:8080/test I get a

> "No such file or directory C:\#{hRand}.html"

Why isn't hRand being replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because string interpolation only works with double quoted strings:

```
File.read("C:\\#{hRand}.html")
```

Comment: Haha! Thanks was breaking my head over it.